# java - download uploaded file with Telegram API

Tags: java, telegram

I want to upload a file with telegram api Uploader and then download it.

To request a download task in downloader I need `volume_id`, `secret` and `localId` but I don't know how can i get this parameters.

Telegram API Uploader just give me a `uniqId` for uploaded file.

How can I get these 3 parameters (volume_id, secret and localId) for uploaded file?

Comment: Is there the online documentation for this Uploader? API description and so on? Also it will be cool if you add request-responce of your API calls.

Comment: I cant find any documentation for that. this is Uploader source code: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi/blob/51713e9b6eb9e0ae0d4bbbe3d4deffff9b7f01e4/src/main/java/org/telegram/api/engine/file/Uploader.java

Comment: nothing? no one worked with rubenlagus telegram api?